# What does the existance of the partial derivative tell us about the continuity in a direction?

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking about the following.

Say that I have a function $f:R^2 \to R$ and that $D_1$ existing. Can I deduce that $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous?

Clearly not, as per numerous examples on this website. My question, though, is deeper. In analysis one proves that if a function is differentiable, then the function must also be continuous. I am curious what does the existence of the partial derivative tell us about the function in terms of continuity. Maybe it is to do with continuity in some direction? But what could that direction be if it is not $x$?

**Question:** What does the existence of the partial derivative tell us about continuity in a certain direction?

If anybody could explain this to me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ is a given function and $y_0\in\Bbb{R}$ is a point such that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, the partial derivative $(D_1f)(x,y_0)$ exists, then it literally means that the function $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, $x\mapsto f(x,y_0)$ is differentiable, and hence continuous. So, we have continuity “along” the line $x\mapsto (x,y_0)$.

What you *cannot* conclude from this is that for each $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $f$ is continuous at $(x,y_0)$. THis is because $f$ is a function of two variables (whereas above we’re considering only a function of one variable, $f(\cdot,y_0)$), and the partial derivative only gives us information about one direction; this is probably what the other answers on the site are referring to.